# Error while creating a view with procedure MySQL

Tags: mysql, view, pivot-table, procedure

I have a problem when I try to create a view using a procedure. I have to do that because I need to make a pivot in MySQL, converting rows of a table in columns of another. 
The query works great, but when I put it in the "CREATE VIEW" statement it gives me error.

Here is the query with CREATE view

```
CREATE VIEW `Untitled` AS 
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(formazioni_persone.id_formazione = ',
      formazioni.id,
      ', true, false)) AS "',
      formazioni.titolo,'"'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM formazioni;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT persone.*, ', @sql, ' FROM persone INNER JOIN formazioni_persone ON persone.id = formazioni_persone.id_persona GROUP BY persone.id');

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql; 

EXECUTE stmt1; 

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

The query without CREATE VIEW `Untitled` AS  works great

The query without CREATE VIEW `Untitled` AS  works great. I already tried to create a TEMP TABLE inside the CREATE VIEW, but nothing. Also tried to use delimiters like that, but nothing

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE VIEW `Untitled` AS 
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(formazioni_persone.id_formazione = ',
      formazioni.id,
      ', true, false)) AS "',
      formazioni.titolo,'"'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM formazioni;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT persone.*, ', @sql, ' FROM persone INNER JOIN formazioni_persone ON persone.id = formazioni_persone.id_persona GROUP BY persone.id');

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql; 

EXECUTE stmt1; 

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Error: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @sql = NULL' at line 2, Time: 0.082000s

Comment: With all due respect, when you make up syntax out of thin air, the chances that it will work are small.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But in MySQL there is no way to make pivot. The only way I found is using IF / CASE. And to make it dynamically (because the table from which I get columns will change) I think I haven't any other solutions... But any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A VIEW is not a procedure. A VIEW is only a single SELECT statement, which must have fixed columns at the time you define the VIEW. You can't make a VIEW that is also a procedure.

Sorry, if you need a pivot-table, you need to specify the values for each column in the query. You can't make a SELECT query or a VIEW that dynamically adds more columns as it finds potential future values.

And you can't define a VIEW that runs an arbitrary block of procedure code anyway. That would require a procedure.

You should just use the solutions that are already shown in questions like [MySQL - Rows to Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns)

There are no other shortcuts or workarounds.

By the way, *all* SQL databases have this restriction, not just MySQL.

---

Re your question:

> I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require manual update of the query

A pivot-table query must have as many columns in the select-list as the number of columns you want it to return. There is no way to make an SQL query that expands the number of columns dynamically as a result of the data it reads at execute time.

The only way you can make a single query that returns all the data is to NOT do a pivot-table query, and instead return all the data in rows, not columns.

```
SELECT p.*, f.titolo, pf.id_persona IS NOT NULL AS ha_formazioni
FROM persone AS p 
CROSS JOIN formazioni AS f
LEFT OUTER JOIN formazioni_persone AS fp ON fp.id_formazioni AND fp.id_persona = p.id
```

This will return one row for each `formazioni` per `persone`. Then you must write code in your application to loop over all the rows of the reesult, and format the data in columns in the manner you want.

Comment: Thank you, now that's clear. Have you got any suggestion to make that dynamic? The number of CASE/IF in the query will change, and I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require manual update of the query